# How to query Many to Many entity using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

1. `User` has many `Roles`
2. `Task` has many `Receivers` ( type of `Role` )

User -> Role

Task -> Role

How can I write a query to get User tasks?
I tried code below, but it returns an `IEnumerable<ICollection>`;

```
v var userTasks = from role in Context.Users.Find(userId).Roles
            join taskRole in Context.Tasks.SelectMany(t => t.Receivers) on role.Id equals taskRole.Id
            select taskRole.Tasks;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the double from clause instead of the join:

```
var userTasks = from role in Context.Users.Find(userId).Roles
                from task in role.Tasks
                select task;
```

Or if you prefer the short way:

```
var userTasks = Context.UserAccount.Find(userID).Roles.SelectMany(role => role.Tasks);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your SelectMany, store the corresponding task

```
Context.Users.Find(userId).Roles
.Join(Context.Tasks.SelectMany(t => t.Receivers.Select(tr => new {t, tr})), 
    r => r.Id, 
    t => t.tr.Id, 
    (r, t) => t.t)
.Distinct() // if task override Equals/HashCode
```

Comment: Why to store the intermediate and distinct the ultimate result when there is a direct path from user to tasks?